# Export default with arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm a beginner in react and I'm a little confused with exporting arrow functions. This code gives me an error saying that App is not defined for both the declaration line and the export default line. If I replace `App = () => ...` with `const App = () =>...`, it works. Why does using an arrow function not work in this situation but using const does? Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
    
App = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>React form handling</h1>
          <form>
            <label>
              First name: <input type="text" />
            </label>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
export default App;
```

Comment: Think about what omitting `const` does here. It doesn't make it not an arrow function, it doesn't make it not a variable, you could replace the arrow function with a regular function and get the same error.

Comment: It's still an arrow function when you use `const`, const is just a way of declaring a variable. When you write `const App = () => ...` you are defining the App variable and setting it's value to the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

That's neither React nor Arrow Functions, **it's JavaScript's ["ES6 modules"](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)** ("import ..." ... "export ...") which are automatically enforcing [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so that you need to *declare* a variable (`const App`) before you can *initialize* it ( `App=...`). You can do declaration and initialization in one step (`const App=...`), but that's still first declare, then initialize.

Outside of modules there's usually no strict mode activated, so that you don't need to declare variables there at all but directly initialize them, what is regarded as *a good start into Spaghetti Code*. Note the worth of finding the place where variables are introduced by eg. being able to search for "*const* App" in larger amounts of code.

Answer (score -1):

It's because without the `const`, it's like assigning a value to an undeclared identifier.

For example, it's like doing this:

```js
toto = 45
```

you need to define toto before that.

Comment: I see! Why can we declare this as a function though? Usually arrow functions work with just using name = ( ) = { }, right?